# SwingTimer update method stalls Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

```
package finalproje;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class GUIMover {
    private ArrayList<JFrame> frameList = new ArrayList<JFrame>();
    private int count, max, matchNumber;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private Timer update;
    private boolean matchFound = false;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public GUIMover(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        matchNumber = random.nextInt(max);
        update = new Timer(500, updateAction);
        update.setCoalesce(true);
    }

    public void startGUI() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Find window " + matchNumber);
        for (; count < max;) {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame(count + "");
            ++count;
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);// exits
                                                                    // windows
                                                                    // when
                                                                    // closed.
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBackground(new Color(random.nextFloat(), random
                    .nextFloat(), random.nextFloat()));
            frame.setBounds(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500),
                    random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500));
            frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                // check if you clicked your match
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                        throws NumberFormatException {
                    if (!matchFound
                            && Integer.parseInt(frame.getTitle()) == matchNumber) {
                        matchFound = true;

                        frameList.get(0).setTitle(
                                "You won after " + getPrintableGameTime()/*
                                                                         * conversion
                                                                         * from
                                                                         * milliseconds
                                                                         * to
                                                                         * seconds
                                                                         */
                                        + " seconds!");
                        for (int q = frameList.size() - 1; q > 0; q--) {
                            frameList.get(q).dispose();
                        }
                        frameList.get(0).setSize(500, 500);
                    }
                }
            });
            frameList.add(frame);
        }
        update.start();
    }
    boolean hasIntersections(JFrame f) {
        for (JFrame x : frameList)
            if (f != x && f.getBounds().intersects(x.getBounds())) {
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
    String getPrintableGameTime() {
        if (matchFound) {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            return String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalTime) / 60,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalTime) % 60);
        } else
            return "You shouldn't see this.";
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    /* serves as update method */
    Action updateAction = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!matchFound) {
                for (JFrame i : frameList) {
                    i.setLocation(
                            (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + random
                                    .nextInt(1000)), (MouseInfo
                                    .getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + random
                                    .nextInt(1000)));
                    i.setLocation(random.nextInt(900), random.nextInt(800));
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < frameList.size(); j++) {
                    while (hasIntersections(frameList.get(j))) {
                        frameList.get(j).setLocation(
                                frameList.get(j).getX() + 10,
                                frameList.get(j).getY());
                        if (frameList.get(j).getX() > 1200) {
                            frameList.get(j).setLocation(0,
                                    frameList.get(j).getY() + 100);
                            frameList.get(j).setSize(
                                    frameList.get(j).getWidth() - 10,
                                    frameList.get(j).getHeight() - 10);

                        } else if (frameList.get(j).getY() > 800) {
                            frameList.get(j).setSize(
                                    frameList.get(j).getWidth() - 10,
                                    frameList.get(j).getHeight() - 10);
                            frameList.get(j).setLocation(0,
                                    frameList.get(j).getX() + 100);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };

}
```

Is it possible to separate the thread which the mouse listener listens on?

While the GUI is moving, any input is ignored, which is very frustrating because this includes the clicking of the close button (red x), which would require me to SIGKILL the process.

Comment: *"which is very frustrating"* GUIs jumping all around the screen is very frustrating. What is this app. supposed to do (besides p*ss people off)?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Based on your previous question on overlapping frames, I'm guessing you are trying to change the location of the frames so they don't overlap. I would look at your "while loop". I'm guessing you have a logic bug and have introduced an infinite loop. Put some debug code in the loop so see if it ever stops executing.

Comment: @camickr The loop isn't infinite, it's just very inefficient, which is fine. Is it possible to make the action of pressing the close button override the while loop's running?

Comment: The GUI can't respond to events until the looping code is finished executing because the looping code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread. You can create a separate Thread for your looping code. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You should look at using a `SwingWorker`.